# Not able to see the print preview in Google Chrome what might be the reason

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

When i try to print the page in "Google Chrome" its not showing up any content, but the content is shown in "Mozilla Firefox". What might be the reason?

The following is the "javascript" code which i have used to print the particular part of the page -

```
 function printItemsLevel(tableClass){
    var html="<html>";
    html+='<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}"></link>';
    html+='<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap-theme.css') }}"></link>';
    html+= document.getElementsByClassName(tableClass)[0].innerHTML;
    html+="</html>";
    var printWin = window.open('','','left=0,top=0,width=960,height=960,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status =0');
    printWin.document.write(html);
    printWin.document.close();
    printWin.focus();
    printWin.print();
    printWin.close();
 }
```

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem should be the window.close after window.print.
Chrome is not waiting for the finish of the printing

try

```
 setTimeout(function(){ printWin.close();}, 10000);
```

instead of

```
printWin.close();
```

so you can check if the browser is chrome in this way

```
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
```

and if true add the setTimeout function, otherwise your code should work

summarizing

```
function printItemsLevel(tableClass){
    var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
    var html="<html>";
    html+='<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}"></link>';
    html+='<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap-theme.css') }}"></link>';
    html+= document.getElementsByClassName(tableClass)[0].innerHTML;
    html+="</html>";
    var printWin = window.open('','','left=0,top=0,width=960,height=960,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status =0');
    printWin.document.write(html);
    printWin.document.close();
    printWin.focus();
    printWin.print();
    if(is_chrome){
      setTimeout(function(){ printWin.close();}, 10000); 
    }
    else{
     printWin.close();
    }

 }
```

if it doesn't work I think it could be an error in innerHTML

if you are inserting html code like "`<header>Test</header>`" it could not work properly in all browser. Try inserting  plain text and let me know if works. If yes I suggest you tu use jquery `html` function in this way

```
$('.tableClass').html(data);
```

Comment: Even after altering with the above code facing the same problem. Is there anything else where I need to alter the code or any code stuff that may workout with the chrome browser

Comment: remove `printWin.document.close();` or shift it after all

Comment: is now working? if no try adding `onload="window.print()"` and `onfocus="window.close()"` to your html body of print window

Comment: are you calling this function on click of an anchor tag? if yes add `return false` at the end of the function

Comment: I am calling this function when clicked on the button with the trigger "onclick". This is the code "  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" id="print-btn" onclick='printItemsLevel("itemsLevelPrint");' >Print</button> "

Comment: could you use jquery? if yes try  `$('.tableClass').html(data);` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName(tableClass)[0].innerHTML;` I think that `innerHTML` is not working properly in Chrome. Try alert it and see the value of the innerHtml property